# Set up SSL on Azure VM (Linux)

Tags: linux, azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-virtual-machine

I currently have an Azure VM (linux) configuration with a custom domain name. Can someone please provide a tutorial (or explain) how I can go about setting up a SSL certificate?

Tried searching but no luck - appreciate all the help!

Comment: there are tons of tutorials explaining how to create an SSL certificate if you google. Just look for SSL CSR creation and install instructions for your preferable web server.

Comment: I did but I assume there are some methods of doing so using Azure panels? this is what im unable to confirm/find

Comment: if you are using virtual machines, you are on your own. Configuration is manual in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

As Bruno has mentioned  in the comment, certificate needs to be configured on OS level.

Here is a good [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-on-arch-linux) about how to create a certificate on Apache.

Azure VM is IaaS. It can not configure the settings on OS directly. That's the reason why we need the [Azure VM Agents](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-agents-and-extensions/).